# rewrite url to non www multiple sites

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have some sites they are running with the same files but different templates, my goal is to force use all www or non www domains.

this is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^[^.]+\.[a-z]{2,5}$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

get it from other question on stackoverflow :)

But if I use www domain all is ok, if not get this redirect

`http://domain.de/www/htdocs/user/_production/http%28?s%29://www.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simplify your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: get server error... not clear what the problem is in this to blocks RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST} %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Actually my bad, there was a space character before `%{REQUEST_URI}`. I edited it, pls try it again.

Comment: great, thank you, how can I exclude some subdomains to be redirected? like admin.domain.com

Comment: You're welcome. You can add a RewriteCond line like this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\.domain\.com$ [NC]` to avoid redirection for `admin.domain.com`